# How to prove that $\dfrac{1}{1+kx}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-x)^nk^n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, induction, power-series

I have recently discovered that:

$\dfrac{1}{1+x}=1-x+x^2-x^3+x^4-x^5+O(x^6)$

$\dfrac{1}{1+2x}=1-2x+2^2x^2-2^3x^3+2^4x^4-2^5x^5+O(x^6)$

$\dfrac{1}{1+3x}=1-3x+3^2x^2-3^3x^3+3^4x^4-3^5x^5+O(x^6)$

and so on

I wish to prove this result by induction but got stuck.

Prove first for $n=1$

$\dfrac{1}{1+x}=1-x+x^2-x^3+x^4-x^5+O(x^6)$ (Why is it true?)

Assume that it is true for $n=k$

Prove that it is true for $n=k+1$

$\dfrac{1}{1+(k+1)x}=1-(k+1)x+(k+1)^2x^2-(k+1)^3x^3+(k+1)^4x^4-(k+1)^5x^5+O(x^6)$

I am stuck at this step, what should I do here?

Comment: This is not an induction proof, you can just plug in $x\mapsto kx$ into the power series to get the desired result.

Comment: Why would you use induction? All of the formulas follow from the first by simply substituting $kx$ for $x$, right?

Comment: How do you this is true for all k? Just because I discover some patterns doesn't mean it is going to hold up for all values of k. This is just wishful thinking, no?

Comment: Do not confuse proving a statement true for an infinite number of values with a proof necessitating induction. Proving $$\frac{d}{dx}(kx)^2 = 2k^2x$$ for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ is just application of chain rule, but does not require induction.

Answer (score 4):

By [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) we have

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-x)^nk^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-xk)^n=\dfrac{1}{1+kx}$$

for $|xk|<1$.